# Show custom dialog with Launch Condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to show the my custom dialog rather than the message box when Launch Condition failed in Wix. Normally, the message box of Launch Condition has OK button, but I would like to make more than that with some further actions with my dialog.
Could you please advise me how I can make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs can be sequenced using the InstallExecuteSequence and Custom elements.  Schedule it prior to your Welcome dialog and after the LaunchConditions action.  You may want an error custom action scheduled in the execute sequence to handle logging during silent installs.

You may also want to author your dialog into the main wizard loop (after install welcome )  using Publish elements also.  It's hard to say without understanding your exact needs.